# Admob Interstitial Time Limit iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to display the admob ad for 30 seconds in my app so it is possible to do any such thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you check following notice from apple : The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench. We will continue to keep you updated

Comment: @Ketan P i know about iAd. I would like to know about Admob full screen ad, is it possible to show ad for specified time limit?

Comment: AdMob does not offer this control. You can specify if you'd only like video interstitial ads on AdMob.com though. Video ads usually disable the *dismiss* button for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you ..Video ads are working as you specified :)

Answer (score 0):

AdMob does not offer this control. You can specify if you'd only like video interstitial ads on AdMob.com though. Video ads usually disable the *dismiss* button for 5 seconds

1. Go to **AdMob.com**
2. Click **Monetize** in the tab bar
3. Select the application on the **left side bar**
4. Select the interstitial **Ad Unit**
5. Deselect **Text** and **Image** so that **Video** is the only remaining ad type